# Exception while launching swagger for .net 6 API using IBM MQ

Tags: iis, swagger, .net-6.0, ibm-mq

I am using IBM MQ nuget package IBMXMSDotnetClient 9.3.4.1 (XMS.net). Visual Studio 2022 and .Net 6.

Launching the swagger in IIS I am getting below error -

Application '/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot.Project.API' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
'dspmqver' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Unhandled exception.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Error reading the  directory.
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
at IBM.WMQ.MQClientCfg.CheckForMqclientIniFileChanges()
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiEnvironment..ctor(NmqiPropertyHandler nmqiPropertyHandler)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.NmqiFactory.GetInstance(NmqiPropertyHandler properties)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Common.WmqPropertyHandler..ctor()
 at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory.InitialiseWMQConnectionFactory()
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqConnectionFactory..ctor(XmsPropertyContext props)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.Factories.WmqFactoryFactory.CreateProviderConnectionFactory(XmsPropertyContext properties)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsConnectionFactoryImpl.SetProviderFactory()
   at IBM.XMS.Admin.Objects.MQConnectionFactory..ctor()
at IBM.XMS.Admin.Objects.WmqXmsFactory.CreateConnectionFactory()
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsFactoryFactoryImpl.CreateConnectionFactory()
```

The apppool is set to Runtime - No managed code

I did IIS reset and browsed, Still getting same error - What is it with mcclient.ini? what location is expected here?

Any help appreciated.

I am not using any MQClient.ini as its not required by application.
"dspmqver" is accessbile and I can run
"C:> dir /b /s C:\setmqenv.cmd"
and
"C:> dir /b /s C:\dspmqver.exe" are giving expected results.

My application is running fine in Visual Studio 2022 and as a Console application
IBM MQ Client 9.3.5
mqclient.ini is created by setup at C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\samp\mqclient.ini

Also, I have given full access to IUSR and application user.

Comment: @Nived J any idea?

Comment: Try setting MQCLNTCF environment variable to point to a empty file called mqclient.ini,  the value must be the full path and file name,  for example C:\tmp\mqclient.ini.

Comment: No effect @JoshMc still same error

Comment: Is there a way to ignore mqclient.ini to be read/used @JoshMc , as I am relying solely on appsettings.json

Comment: It was just a suggestion.   The proper route to support is to open a case with IBM under the support contact that covers your production queue mangers.   It seems like a defect to me.   You can Google mqclient.ini locations to see all the places the client normally looks and try placing a empty file in each to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be related to the bitness of the IBM MQ nuget package. You can try to set enable 32-bit application in iis to solve the problem.

Go to Website >Select the application pool your 32-bit application will run under > Click Advanced setting > Set Enable 32-bit Applications to True.